# Unable to retrive Projection/Multi- Relantion field Requests.Custom_SFDCChangeReqID2 using versionone java sdk

Tags: java, api, sdk, versionone

I have been trying to retrieve information from querying a specific Asset(Story/Defect) on V1 using the VersionOne.SDK.Java.APIClient. I have been able to retrieve information like `ID.Number`, Status.Name but not `Requests.Custom_SFDCChangeReqID2` under a Story or a Defect.

I check the metadata for:

```
https://.../Story?xsl=api.xsl
https://.../meta.V1/Defect?xsl=api.xsl
https://.../meta.V1/Request?xsl=api.xsl
```

And the naming and information looks right.

Here is my code:

```
IAssetType type = metaModel.getAssetType("Story");

IAttributeDefinition requestCRIDAttribute = type.getAttributeDefinition("Requests.Custom_SFDCChangeReqID2");

IAttributeDefinition idNumberAttribute =    type.getAttributeDefinition("ID.Number")

Query query = new Query(type);
query.getSelection().add(requestCRIDAttribute);
query.getSelection().add(idNumberAttribute);

Asset[] results = v1Api.retrieve(query).getAssets();
String RequestCRID=    result.getAttribute(requestCRIDAttribute).getValue().toString();
String IdNumber= result.getAttribute(idNumberAttribute).getValue().toString();
```

At this point, I can get some values for ID.Number but I am not able to retrieving any information for the value `Custom_SFDCChangeReqID2`.

When I run the restful query to retrieve information using a browser from a server standpoint it works and it does retrieve the information I am looking for. I used this syntax:

https://.../rest-1.v1/Data/Story?sel=Number,ID,Story.Requests.Custom_SFDCChangeReqID2,Story.

Answer (score 1):

Alex: Remember that Results is an array of Asset´s, so I guess you should be accessing the information using something like
String RequestCRID=    **results[0]**.getAttribute(requestCRIDAttribute).getValue().toString();
String IdNumber= **results[0]**.getAttribute(idNumberAttribute).getValue().toString();
or Iterate through the array.
Also notice that you have defined:
Asset[] **results**  and not **result**

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! I completly forgot about representing the loop, I was too focus on the retriving information part, yes I awas actually using

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for your answer! I completely forgot about representing the loop, I was too focus on the retriving information part, yes I was actually using a loop and yes I created a temporary variable to check what I was getting from the query in the form
Because I was getting the variables one by one so I was only using the first record. My code works after all. It was just that What I was querying didn't contain any information of my use, that's why I was not finding any. Anyway thanks for your comment and observations